# php7.2 + nginx + memcache. style.css and script.js in memcache passworded subdirectory not retrieved

Tags: nginx, directory, passwords

I set password on memcache directory and index.php runs fine. But it is not styled properly. I looked into it and at first I got "access denied" error in nginx log. Then I added these lines

```
     location ~ \.js {
        add_header Content-Type application/javascript;
        add_header Content-Encoding gzip;
        expires 365d;
     }
     location ~ \.css {
        add_header Content-Type text/css;
        add_header Content-Encoding gzip;
        expires 30d;
     }
```

and started to get blank script.js and style.css in my browser. There are no mistakes in nginx logs.
Then I checked subdirectories permissions.

```
    drwxr-xr-x 5 www-data www-data  4096 сен  1  2016 Public/
    drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 сен  1  2016 Images/
    drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 сен  1  2016 Scripts/
    drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 сен  1  2016 Styles/
    -rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 3673 май 30  2012 Style.css
    -rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 10422 янв 27  2012 Script.js
```

So nothing works. How do I get these files rendered?

```
    location ^~ /memcache/ {
142
143
144                 auth_basic "Restricted";
145                 auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
146
147
148
149                 location ~ \.js {
150                 add_header Content-Type application/javascript;
151                 add_header Content-Encoding gzip;
152                 expires 30d;
153                 }
154                 location ~ \.css {
155                 add_header Content-Type text/css;
156                 add_header Content-Encoding gzip;
157                 expires 30d;
158                 }
159
160
161
162
163
164         location ~ \.php$ {
165
166
167          fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
168          fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
169          fastcgi_index index.php;
170          include fastcgi_params;
171          fastcgi_intercept_errors        on;
172          fastcgi_ignore_client_abort     on;
173          fastcgi_connect_timeout 600;
174          fastcgi_send_timeout 180;
175          fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
176          fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
177          fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
178          fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
179          fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
180 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
location ~ \.js {
add_header Content-Type application/javascript;
add_header Content-Encoding gzip;    # removing this line worked like magic
expires 30d;
}
location ~ \.css {
add_header Content-Type text/css;
add_header Content-Encoding gzip;   #and this one too
expires 30d;
}
```

I forgot that the rest of the site used gzipped css and js. Which I have not planned for protected phpMemcacheAdmin folder.